# Do white house and congressional staffers currently (or sans Obamacare) receive subsidies for their health insurance?

Tags: united-states, budget, healthcare, government-shutdown

The House passed a CR last night or today that would have delayed the individual mandate for 1 year and removed subsidies for congressional staffers, white house staffers, etc if they purchase health insurance through exchanges.

Last month (i.e., before the exchanges went live) were these folks receiving subsidies for health insurance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.factcheck.org/2009/08/health-care-for-members-of-congress/

> Members of Congress have good health insurance by any standard, but
>   it’s not free and not reserved only for them – and it’s not government
>   insurance. House and Senate members are allowed to purchase private
>   health insurance offered through the Federal Employees Health Benefits
>   Program, **which covers more than 8 million other federal employees,
>   retirees and their families**.
>
> [T]he government pays a large share of the cost of coverage. On
>   average, the government pays 72 percent of the premiums for its
>   workers, up to a maximum of 75 percent depending on the policy chosen.
>   For example, the popular Blue Cross and Blue Shield standard
>   fee-for-service family plan carries a total premium of $1,327.80 per
>   month, of which the beneficiary pays $430.04. Washington, D.C.-based
>   employees who prefer an HMO option might choose the Kaiser standard
>   family plan. It carries a total premium of $825.15 per month, of which
>   the employee pays only $206.29.

Comment: Does this apply specifically to staffers?

Comment: @Mikeazo - It applies to all US Federal government employees.  If you read further down in the article there are other benefits that are specific to members of congress but are not relevent to this question

Comment: All, full-time US federal government employees, right? I'm not sure all staffers are full-time. I guess I'm also not sure that non-full-time staffers will get the obamacare subsidy.

Comment: @mikeazo - any employee eligible for employee health benefits... there are probably some positions that are less than full time that are eligible.